# generate runtime xml in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have genarated a xml file through the asp.net code as

```
 public bool createxml()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        clsRegister obj = new clsRegister();
        int i = 0;
        string strpath = string.Empty;
        XmlTextWriter objwriter = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
        ds = obj.searchgallery(4);
        try
        {
            strpath = "d:\\hellojhasi\\glance\\jhansigallery\\gallery.xml";
            objwriter = new XmlTextWriter(strpath, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                   objwriter.WriteStartElement("picturegallery");
                    objwriter.WriteElementString("fullimage", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["fullimage"].ToString());
                    objwriter.WriteElementString("thumbnail", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["thumbnail"].ToString());
                    objwriter.WriteElementString("title", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["title"].ToString());
                    objwriter.WriteElementString("description", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["description"].ToString());
                    objwriter.WriteElementString("height", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["height"].ToString());
                    objwriter.WriteElementString("width", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["width"].ToString());
                    objwriter.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            else
            {

                objwriter.WriteEndElement();
            }
            objwriter.Flush();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return true;
    }
```

the code executed well.
but the xml file when opens gives the following error

The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document. Error processing resource 'file:///D:/HelloJhasi/glance/jhansigal...

can anyone plz help me with this

Answer (score 0):

DataSet has a built in function that save to the xml file, you can do it like this

```
    string  strpath = "d:\\hellojhasi\\glance\\jhansigallery\\gallery.xml";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    clsRegister obj = new clsRegister();
    int i = 0;
    string strpath = string.Empty;
    XmlTextWriter objwriter = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
    ds = obj.searchgallery(4);
    ds.WriteXml(strpath);
```

You are getting that error, because only one top level element is allowed in an XML document, for example

```
<root>
   ...
</root>
<root>
   ...
</root>
```

Is not valid XML

```
<root>
   <root>
      ...
   </root>
   ...
</root>
```

Is valid